# how to find range of a continous variable where a count variable is non-zero R

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to find the range of variable lat for each other column containing occurence records e.g. 0,1,2,3 etc. where the record of occurrence is non-zero (range of lat where occurence >0). I've tried to subset the data for each column without rows with 0 individuals recorded but I can't get it to work.

[image: my data]

i tried to extract the minimum and maximum of lat for each species column where the occurence was >0 using which.max/min:

```
allfreq$lat[which.min(allfreq$lat[allfreq$Fem.mad !=0])]
```

however the results made no sense in that the values were nowhere near the minimum and maximum I observed visually.

Answer (score 0):

Using mtcars dataset

```
> sapply(mtcars,function(x){range(x[x!=0])})

      mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt qsec vs am gear carb
[1,] 10.4   4  71.1  52 2.76 1.513 14.5  1  1    3    1
[2,] 33.9   8 472.0 335 4.93 5.424 22.9  1  1    5    8
```